# SFTP - overriden permissions (filemask, owner/group)

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp, openssh

I am running an OpenSSH sftp-server (Linux, Raspbian) and FileZilla is used as client. The problems I experienced were that the user could delete any file on the server with no regard to the filemask or the owner/group:

User that logs in:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep sftp     
sftp-guest:x:1001:1004:::/sbin/nologin
```

Group:

```
cat /etc/group | grep sftp-only
sftp-only:x:1004:
```

This is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config - file (shadowed Port):

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port ***33
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

#X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net
Banner /sftp/welcome_message

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
#AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM yes

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group *,!sftp-only,!pi
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        ChrootDirectory /sftp/empty

Match group sftp-only
        ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

As you can see in the sshd_config the user sftp-guest is chrooted into /sftp/sftp-guest.
Here you can see the permissions of the files/folders:

```
ll /sftp | grep sftp-guest
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 20 02:26 sftp-guest

ll /sftp/sftp-guest/
drwxrwxr-x 9 sftp-guest pi   4096 Apr 18 22:18 maturaprojekt

ll /sftp/sftp-guest/data/
---------- 1 sftp-guest sftp-only  205 Apr 18 22:06 readme
---------- 1 root       root       205 Apr 18 22:18 readme2
```

The problem is that both files (readme, readme2) can be deleted with Filezilla or via sftp (commandline). Futher renaming or changing the permissions is possible.

EDIT --> 
When trying to view or download these files the transfer fails!
Filezilla-Log:

```
Command:    get "readme" "/tmp/fz3temp-1/readme"
Error:  /data/readme: open for read: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed

Command:    get "readme" "/home/michael/data/readme"
Error:  /data/readme: open for read: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
```

<-- EDIT

My question is now how this behavior could be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right to delete a file is on the parent folder : if the folder is writable, you can delete a file inside. Try a `chmod -w /sftp/sftp-guest/data/` to prevent sftp-guest from deleting the readme files (you can also make them readable to fix your last edit).

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction!
The problem with your solution would be that the user couldn't upload files anymore (didn't mention that, though).
The solution is called '[sticky bit](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/file-removal.html)':
chmod 1777 /sftp/sftp-guest/data.
Now everyone can create files/dirs in this directory but only the owner of the file/dir can delete/modify them (like /tmp on linux).